# How to calculate the space I need for the indexes?

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
CREATE TABLE info(
home CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
galaxy TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
galaxy_pos INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
events TEXT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY(galaxy, galaxy_pos, id), PRIMARY KEY(home, id)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

10+1+1+4+2 = `18 bytes + TEXT`, are needed for the data. How to calculate the space I need for the indexes?

Answer (score 2):

For the data record add:

- 6 bytes transaction id
- 7 bytes rollback pointer
- 5 bytes extra bytes header
- 2 bytes - for length of TEXT field (however if TEXT values longer than 7k overhead will be bigger)

Index record stores indexed fields + primary key. So its length will be

- 5 bytes - extra bytes
- indexed fields length
- primary key length (in your case it's 1+4+1 bytes)

Take into account an InnoDB page may be filled up to 15/16 i.e. 15k of data+headers.

Each page has 120 bytes in headers.

Plus take into account space that is used by non-leaf pages. It's not huge, but still.

Comment: Primary key length here is 10+1, not 1+4+1.

Comment: ah, yes. I thought UNIQUE KEY(galaxy, galaxy_pos, id) will be a PK

Comment: Also it's close to impossible to calculate how many pages is going to be needed unless you can be sure that the size of your elements is fixed (which it usually is in an index, but that assumes you get the size right!) There is also some OS overhead (inodes used to track the inodes used by your file). So I would just do a x2 on the basic amount and not try to consider each byte taken. That way you a good idea and you don't want your HD to fill up anyway.